# Javascript that will execute on only child pages of a specific parent

Tags: javascript, child-pages

Semi-new to WordPress, so apologies is this is an obvious question!

I'm trying to execute some JavaScript on a WordPress site, but only on the child pages of a specific parent page - so, I have example.com/books, and I want the script to run on example.com/books/foo, example.com/books/bar, example.com/books/wee, and so forth. I don't want it to run on example.com/books.

I know that I could just add in the script on each individual page, but I have other people editing the site who may add new book child pages, and they will not feel comfortable adding in Javascript.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't quite cover how far you got and if you are familiar with basic of WP enqueue process.

Focusing on parent part I the basic code would go like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    if ( is_page() && in_array( $book_page_id, get_post_ancestors( get_the_id() ) ) ) {

        // enqueue stuff
    }
} );
```

In your examples you only have one level and might have worked to just check `post_parent` of current post, but checking for ancestors is more thorough for more nested cases.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Rarst answer if you are looking for using slug of `books` page. I have written a small function to check if it is a child page of any given page.

You can use it to enqueue JavaScript conditionally.

```
function wpse_228256_is_child_of($page) {
    $current_post = get_post();

    //First check if it is child of any page to skip the processing on other parent pages/posts
    if ( !empty($current_post->post_parent) ) {
        $target_page = get_page_by_path($page); //Now get the target page
        $top_parent = array_pop( get_post_ancestors( $current_post ) ); //Get the top parent
        if (isset($target_page->ID) && $target_page->ID == $top_parent) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE; //Return false for everything else 
}
```

Now you can use it to enqueue your script on child page of a given parent page.

Example:-

```
if (wpse_228256_is_child_of('books')) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
    });
}
```

OR if you don't have js file and just want to print few lines in `head`

```
if (wpse_228256_is_child_of('books')) {
    add_action('wp_head', function(){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('I am child page of books');
        </script><?php
    });
}
```